# Processing excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet with a list of experiments, as shown in the picture below. How can I access specific rows and columns to find the mean and std dev? I am able to load the excel file and read the data using pandas, but I am not sure where to go from there. Ideally, the code can process sheets with many experiment results listed.

[Excel input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UddY2.png)

For output, I would like a table summarizing the results, as shown in the picture below:

[Result Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUn6Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is efficient solution, but this will do.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("~/Desktop/delete.xlsx", header=None).T

df.dropna(axis=1, inplace = True)

df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace = True) 

df.drop(df.index[0], inplace = True)

cols = df.columns.unique()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(3, 8), columns=cols)

df1['mean'] = df1[df1.columns[~df1.columns.isin(['Test','Sample', 'Site'])]].mean(axis=1)

df1['std'] =  df1[df1.columns[~df1.columns.isin(['Test','Sample', 'Site'])]].std(axis=1)

print(df1[['Sample', 'mean', 'std']])
```